# anchor tag with span inside is not clickable

Tags: html, css

I am using a span inside anchor tag which are inside `<li>`. Due to some unknown reason, one anchor tag is clickable and other is partially clickable (only the `<span>` part). Below is the code:

```
<div id="catIcons">
  <ul class="catList">
    <li><a href="" title="" class="catAir"><span>Travel &amp; Airline</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="" class="catEcom"><span>eCommerce &amp; Coupons</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="catList">
    <li><a href="" title="" class="catSearch"><span>Classifieds </span></a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="" class="catSocial"><span>Social Media &amp; UCG</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS Used:

```
.catList{width:142px; float:left; margin:0 7px 0 0;list-style:none;padding:0;}
.catList li{margin-bottom:5px;}
.catList li a{display:block;padding-top:60px;}
.catList li span{font-size:11px;font-weight:normal; color:#fff; text-align:center; padding:2px 0; margin:0 auto; display:block; background-color:#2A79B2; -moz-border-radius:5px; -webkit-border-radius:5px; border-radius:5px;}
.catAir{background:url('/images/category_icons.jpg') no-repeat 44px 8px;}
.catEcom{background:url('/images/category_icons.jpg') no-repeat -492px 8px;}
```

Please refer to this link for more information: http://184.106.132.165/index.php

Thank you

Comment: I found what the problem was. A slider on the page was positioned absolutely and had higher z-index value. It was covering half the anchor tag. So I positioned my div as absolute and gave it a hihger z-index value. Please suggest if there exists any better solution.

Comment: Please post all necessary information in the question. Referring to the page you are developing will remove the information when you have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning a value to the `href` attribute on each anchor. For example:

```
<a href="#" title="" class="catAir">...</a>
```